# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$ where $T_n$ is the number of distinct partitions of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$

Tags: analysis

> A partition of set $\Omega_n=\{1,\cdots,n\}$ is a family of nonempty sets $\{B_i\}$ where $\bigcup_iB_i=\Omega_n$ and $B_i\cap B_j=\emptyset\,(j\ne i)$. $\{\Omega_n\}$ is also a partition of $\Omega_n$.
>   Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$ where $T_n$ is the number of distinct partition of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$.

I am stuck in how to evaluate $T_n$.

Comment: The Wikipedia has a summary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Generating_function